# Elastic beanstalk / Django Cache intermittently displaying wrong value

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a site deployed to Elastic Beanstalk -- I've written some data to a Django memory cache, and when retrieving it i get two different values.

It would seem to me that there are multiple instances, but looking at my control panel, there seems to only be one web instance running right now. 
i output the value in a log message and i see there are multiple PIDs.

```
[Wed Oct 21 14:21:34.922493 2015] [:error] [pid 14335] WARNING:root:Cached: After tomorrow, Back to the Future will take place entirely in the past.
[Wed Oct 21 14:21:35.133714 2015] [:error] [pid 14337] WARNING:root:Cached: Bacon and eggs is a day's work for a chicken and a lifetime achievement for a pig.
[Wed Oct 21 14:21:35.319643 2015] [:error] [pid 14337] WARNING:root:Cached: Bacon and eggs is a day's work for a chicken and a lifetime achievement for a pig.
[Wed Oct 21 14:21:35.521985 2015] [:error] [pid 14335] WARNING:root:Cached: After tomorrow, Back to the Future will take place entirely in the past.
[Wed Oct 21 14:21:35.690560 2015] [:error] [pid 14336] WARNING:root:Cached: Bacon and eggs is a day's work for a chicken and a lifetime achievement for a pig.
```

It seems to randomly toggle between the two values/pids.

I'm sure there's only one web node running - is there some way there are multiple instances of the application running on a single node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single EC2 instance with a single webserver (Apache, by default). However, Apache will create more than one worker process, each of which will run a separate instance of your Django app. When you make a request to your server, either one of the worker processes may answer it, which is why you're seeing the two values arbitrarily.

If you need a single cache across your application, you'd be better suited looking at running Memcached or Redis locally (for a single EC2 node) or using Amazon's ElastiCache service.